# How to redirect chrome browser to its set homepage using javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am trying to use javascript to redirect to browsers homepage when users logoff a web application.
I got this working in IE using `window.location.href = "about:home"`

However for Chrome and Edge it is not working.I tried `window.home();` and it does not work too.

Please help me with this.Thank you for your answers.

Comment: For chrome it is `chrome://newtab/`

Answer (score 1):

Try this one line solution supporting all the major browsers:

```
window.location.href = browser == 'gc' ? 'chrome://newtab/' : browser == 'op' ? 'about:speeddial' : browser=='sa' ? 'http://livepage.apple.com' : 'about:home';
```

Comment: @Zachy why not try `'chrome://newtab/'`

Comment: @ZackVT , @MMJM - gives me the below error

`window.location.href='chrome://newtab'
VM339:1 Not allowed to load local resource: chrome://newtab/`

So it does not work

Comment: I tried `'https://www.google.com/_/chrome/newtab'` it does load a newtab but does not redirect to homepage set in users browser